# Float to char array

Tags: arrays, c

As a 55-year-old newcomer to programming, there is one point I can't understand in floats.

Let's say I have a float like

```
float my_fl = 1.00f
```

When I want to store this value in a char array I can simply use **memcpy**

```
char  bytes[4];

memcpy(bytes, &my_fl, sizeof(float));

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(float); ++i)
    printf("Byte %zu is 0x%02x.\n", i, bytes[i]);
```

I want to print this array to console, but I see different values instead of `0x3f800000`

Can you help me where I went wrong?

Comment: Your experiencing sign-extension. Change `bytes` to `unsigned char bytes[ sizeof(float) ];`

Comment: I have to say -- a newcomer to programming and you're thinking about stuff like this, wondering what the floating point representation actually looks like. Wow. That's kind of impressive.

Comment: FYI here it doesn't matter you don't need to copy the bytes, you can just read them by casting the address to a char*: `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&f)` - note this _only_ works for (unsigned) char (and `std::byte`).

Comment: @ikegami yeah but OP said that's _not_ what they saw. Presumably got some random-looking bungled up output.

Comment: @ikegami Did you *read* the question. The OP stated *"I see different values instead of 0x3f800000"* . The reason for that is exactly because of what I stated.

Comment: *...but I see different values instead of...*  What different values did you see?

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. Edit the question to provide a [mre]. In particular, your post is missing a sample of the observed output. Quite likely you are seeing “0xffffff80” in “Byte 2”, and that would be due to the fact that `char` is signed in your C implementation, so the byte is negative and more bits are set when it is automatically promoted to `int` to pass to `printf`. Generally, you should use `unsigned char` when working with the bytes that represent objects.

Comment: @Eljay `0xffffff80`

Comment: The reason you saw `0xffffff80` is because on your system `char` is implicitly signed.  You can work around that by doing `printf("Byte %zu is 0x%02x.\n", i, bytes[i] & 0xFF);` or by doing `unsigned char bytes[4];`.

Comment: @Cubic, woops! Misread the question. Comment and answer deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running this code gives the following output:

```
Byte 0 is 0x00.
Byte 1 is 0x00.
Byte 2 is 0xffffff80.
Byte 3 is 0x3f.
```

Because you're using `char` to store the bytes, and on your system (and most in fact) a `char` is signed.  Then when a `char` is passed to `printf` which is a variadic function, a value of type `char` is *promoted* to type `int`.

In the case of byte 2 which contains the representation 0x80, this representation as a signed `char` has the value -128.  When promoted to a `int`, you still have the value -128 but its representation is 0xffffff80 which is what gets printed with `%x`.

If you change the type of `bytes` to `unsigned char`, the values in the array will all be positive regardless of the representation, so there will be no sign extension when the values are promoted.

Comment: Props for actually answering the posted question. Indeed I suspect the OP was (a) not considering the signed-ness of `char`, and (b) even more elusive to someone unfamiliar to it, the effects of sign extension during variadic integer promotion.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your code roughly looks like this: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/x7EnrcYWc)

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    float my_fl = 1.00f;
    char  bytes[4];
    memcpy(bytes, &my_fl, sizeof(float));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(float); ++i)
        printf("Byte %zu is 0x%02x.\n", i, (int)bytes[i]);
}
```

The output would most likely be:

```
Byte 0 is 0x00.
Byte 1 is 0x00.
Byte 2 is 0xffffff80.
Byte 3 is 0x3f.
```

The reasons for this are:

##### 1. Sign-extension

In order to correctly keep negative values when converting to larger integral type, the sign needs to be extended.

Example:

```cpp
char a = 1; // 0x01
int b = a;  // 0x00000001

char c = -1; // 0xFF
int d = c;   // 0xFFFFFFFF // (not 0x000000FF!)
```

The process for this is relatively simple: if the highest bit is set a signed number has a negative value.

- If the number is 0 or positive, fill the added bits in front with 0's.
- If the number is negative, fill the added bits in front with 1's.

The reason why this is happening is because variadic arguments (like it is the case with `printf`) promote their integral parameters - so `bool`, `char`, `short`, etc... will all be promoted to `int`s.

You can easily fix this in one of 2 ways:

###### 1.1 Make the char array unsigned

unsigned numbers don't have negative values, so no sign extension happens for them.

e.g.: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/T1M11bqfx)

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    float my_fl = 1.00f;
    unsigned char  bytes[4];
    memcpy(bytes, &my_fl, sizeof(float));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(float); ++i)
        printf("Byte %zu is 0x%02x.\n", i, (int)bytes[i]);
}
```

###### 1.2 tell printf that it's actually dealing with a `char`

`printf` doesn't know that you passed a `char`, since it gets promoted to `int` before the call.

But you can use a size-specifier to let it know that you want to treat it as a `char`, not an `int`.

For `char` the size-specifier would be `hh`, e.g.: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GhKoqe7ET)

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    float my_fl = 1.00f;
    char  bytes[4];
    memcpy(bytes, &my_fl, sizeof(float));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(float); ++i)
        printf("Byte %zu is 0x%02hhx.\n", i, (int)bytes[i]);
}
```

##### 2. Endianness

Depending on the architecture your PC is running on it could be little-endian or big-endian.
<sup>(or middle-endian)</sup>

e.g.:

- IA-32, x86-64, ... are little-endian
- AVR32, OpenRISC, SPARC, ... are big-endian
- AArch64, RISC-V, ... can be operated either as little- or big-endian

Depending on the endianness the output of your program can vary:

- Little Endian:

  ```
  Byte 0 is 0x00.
  Byte 1 is 0x00.
  Byte 2 is 0x80.
  Byte 3 is 0x3f.
  ```
- Big Endian:

  ```
  Byte 0 is 0x3f.
  Byte 1 is 0x80.
  Byte 2 is 0x00.
  Byte 3 is 0x00.
  ```
- Mid-little Endian (one example of the Middle-Endian group):

  ```
  Byte 0 is 0x00.
  Byte 1 is 0x00.
  Byte 2 is 0x3f.
  Byte 3 is 0x80.
  ```

Since C++20 there's a language built-in way now to check for which endianness you're compiling for:

```cpp
if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::big) {
  // big endian
} else if constexpr(std::endian::native == std::endian::little) {
  // little endian
} else {
  // some form of middle endian
}
```